# IOS add custom attribute to uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, custom-attributes

I am trying to achieve this sort of thing in my IOS app in xcode.

Html:
`<div data-foo="foobar"></div>`

Basically, I have a uitableviewcell, and I want to add a custom attribute that I can get and set.

I know I can use the `detailTextLabel.text` and make the text transparent, but what I really need is something behind the scenes that I can set and get, like the `data-foo` in html, but in xcode/ios with a `uiTableViewCell`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Why do you think you need that? Store your data-foo in the dataSource. Explain what you **really** want to do. Do you want to reference UIControls like UITextViews or UIButtons in your cells? You don't need data-foo for this. In my opinion everything is possible with the indexPath

Comment: @MatthiasBauch I need this to store data that I can use for deleting enteries from the table and data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could make a class called MyTableCell, and create some objects there. In the storyboard, set the TableViewCell to MyTableViewCell. Then when you create a TableViewCell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyTableCell"];

//configure cell
//make any changes to the TableViewCell class with cell.myObject    

return cell;
}
```